# LWJGL Mouse scroll wheel getDWheel() Method

Tags: java, input, lwjgl, mousewheel

I use the getDWheel method in my game like so:

```
public void checkMouseWheel() {
if (highLight != null) {
    if (Mouse.getDWheel() < 0) {
        System.out.println("DOWN");
    }
    if (Mouse.getDWheel() > 0){
        System.out.println("UP");
   }
}
```

I call this method every time I check for input. When I use the scroll wheel the program only reaches the DOWN part when I scroll up, It doesn't get into the if... No matter what I do only the scroll down works.

EDIT: When I scroll down ingame it prints "DOWN" but when I scroll up ingame nothing is printed.

Comment: And what's the  problem?

Comment: edited. scrolling up doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the javadoc, `Mouse.getDWheel()` "returns Movement of the wheel since last time getDWheel() was called"

So when you call it the first time, the information is 'cleared out', and therefore will always return 0 for the second call. Try this small change to fix it:

```
public void checkMouseWheel() {
if (highLight != null) {
    int dWheel = Mouse.getDWheel();
    if (dWheel < 0) {
        System.out.println("DOWN");
    } else if (dWheel > 0){
        System.out.println("UP");
   }
}
```